# Are there any reasons to not use smallint when it fits the data?

Tags: postgresql, integer

Since PostgreSQL doesn't have 1-byte tinyint, the second best option would be smallint. However, I've read from various posts that it may actually be slower because CPU's are optimized to operate on 32-bit integers, or there may be implicit conversions to 32-bit integers.

Besides these reasons, are there any other reasons I'm not yet aware of for not using integers smaller than 32-bits?

Comment: There is also the special (internal) type `"char"` (quotes required) that uses 1 byte: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-character.html but it is not recommended for use.

Comment: I'm curious where you read that `smallint` would be less efficient than `int`.

Comment: I can't find it now, and I could be wrong about this. What I understood from it is that smaller integers would save disk/index space. So, good for the database, but the web/computation server would need to convert it to 32-bit

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I couldn't figure out how to use `char` type in Django, it doesn't appear to be natively supported. It would also have to work as the PK for a table of 255>rows>10 to select from, so a character wouldn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Note it's not `char`, it's ``"char"`. But yeah, if one was going to use it, he would have to convert it to (and form) some nice format, say integer 0-255, for display purposes. And no idea how (or if) Django could use it.

Comment: It all depends ... One of the caveats of using `smallint` is demonstrated in this question on SO yesterday: [GIN index on smallint\[\] column not used or error “operator is not unique”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39798993/939860) ...

Answer (score -1):

If you have determined that using smallint is appropriate for your scenario, you can simply declare the column as smallint when creating the table. Here's an example of creating a table with a smallint column:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  value smallint
);
```